# Howto remove HTML <a> tags in a CDATA element

Tags: html, xml, string, cdata

I have HTML in a CDATA element (HTML is too crappy to be parsed) and I would like to remove `<a href>` tags, but keep text in the tags.

I'm searching around regex but still not find a good way to do that.

All advices are welcome!

Comment: Some examples of input and desired output would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* remove anything from a string that *looks like* a HTML link via regex. Results heavily depend on your input, but replacing `</?a\b[^>]*>` with the empty string could get you pretty far.

In any case, handling HTML with regular expressions is crappy and ad-hoc. If your input data set is limited and well known and all you need to do is some throw-away one-time conversion code then crappy and ad-hoc may be enough and you could get away with it.

If you are developing code that is intended to be of the long-lived sort, you should definitely look into one of the avilable HTML parsers ([BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for Python or the [HTML Agility Pack for](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) .NET come to mind) and not only handle your HTML in a structured way, but also fix it while you are at it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact this just a one-shot export so it's not a problem.
I'm searching now for a xslt 2 processor supporting replace function on Ubuntu.